# How to replace one digit numbers by two digits numbers using stringr in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want to replace the values of column x `s1_`, `s2_`, `s9_` and `s10_` by `s01_`, `s02_`, `s09_` and `s10_`. I can easily do it for each case (e.g. `s1_`) but not for all (my regex knowledge is short).
How can I do all those replacements without repeating myself?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble( x = c('s1_', 's2_', 's9_', 's10_'))

pattern <- 's1_'  
replacement <-  's01_'  
stringr::str_replace(df$x, pattern, replacement)      
#> [1] "s01_" "s2_"  "s9_"  "s10_"
Created on 2020-11-12 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option with `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
df$x <- gsubfn("(\\d+)", ~sprintf('%02d', as.numeric(x)), df$x)
```

---

Similar to `gsubfn`, the `str_replace` replacement can take a function

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(df$x, "\\d+", function(x) sprintf('%02d', as.numeric(x)))
#[1] "s01_" "s02_" "s09_" "s10_"
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(x = str_replace(x, "\\d+", 
          purrr::as_mapper(~ sprintf('%02d', as.numeric(.x)))))
```